# Expectation for a product of Geometric random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

> **Problem:** Let $X$ be Geometric$(p)$. Show for $r = 2,3,4\dots$, that 
>   $$E[X(X-1)\dots(X-r+1)]=\frac{r!p^r}{(1-p)^r}$$

**Attempt:** $P(X=k)=p^k(1-p)$
\begin{align}E[X(X-1)\dots(X-r+1)]&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty k(k-1)\dots(k-r+1)p^k(1-p)\\[0.3cm]^{\text{As the terms when $k < r$ turn out to be $0$.}}&=\sum_{k=r}^\infty k(k-1)\dots(k-r+1)p^k(1-p)
\\[0.3cm]&=r!\sum_{k=r}^\infty \binom{k}{r} p^k(1-p)
\\[0.3cm]&=r!\frac{p^r}{(1-p)^{r-1}}\sum_{k=r}^\infty \binom{k}{r} p^{k-r}(1-p)^{r}\end{align}

I got stuck then, could you please give me some hint on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perhaps simpler to observe that the probability generating function defined by $$P_X(t) = \operatorname{E}[t^X]$$ obeys the relationship $$\left[\frac{d^r P_X(t)}{dt^r}\right]_{t=1} = P_X^{(r)}(1) = \operatorname{E}[X(X-1)\ldots (X-r+1)], \quad r = 1, 2, \ldots,$$ whenever such moments are defined.  Then for a geometric random variable with $$\Pr[X = x] = p^x (1-p), \quad x = 0, 1, 2, \ldots,$$ we immediately have $$P_X(t) = \sum_{x=0}^\infty t^x p^x (1-p) = \frac{1-p}{1-pt}, \quad |t| < 1/p.$$  Computing successive derivatives with respect to $t$ leads to the pattern
$$P_X'(t) = p(1-p)(1-pt)^{-2}, \\
P_X''(t) = 2p^2(1-p)(1-pt)^{-3}, \\
P_X'''(t) = 6p^3(1-p)(1-pt)^{-4}, \\
\ldots,$$
hence $$P_X^{(r)}(t) = \frac{r! p^r (1-p)}{(1-pt)^{r+1}},$$ where upon evaluating at $t = 1$ gives the desired result.

---

Alternatively, we can use the [(generalized) binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) and compute the expectation directly, first observing that $$X(X-1)\ldots (X-r+1) = \frac{X!}{(X-r)!} = r! \binom{X}{r}, \quad X \ge r,$$ and $0$ otherwise.  Hence $$\operatorname{E}[X(X-1)\ldots (X-r+1)] = r! (1-p) \sum_{x=r}^\infty \binom{x}{r} p^x,$$ and the result immediately follows.

Comment: I understand it now, thank you!

Comment: I think the OP got stuck at the last sum of the "alternatively way", so perhaps he does not see that "the result immediately follows". Can you please elaborate on this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Change of bound variable: $$\sum_{k=r}^\infty \binom k{k-r}p^{k-r}(1-p)^{r} ~=~ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+r}{n}p^n (1-p)^r$$

Which you should (but may not) recognise as the [negative binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series#Special_cases).

> $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+r}n p^n = \frac{1}{(1-p)^{r+1}}$$

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand why this solves the problem. I understand (k choose r) = (k choose k-r) and I am assuming you intend to use the binomial theorem (p+(1-p))^(n+r) = 1 = (n+r choose 0) p^0(1-p)^(n+r)+...(n+r choose n+r) p^(n+r)(1-p)^0. However n is not fixed here, in this way, can we still use the binomial theorem?

Comment: I understand it now, thank you a lot!

Comment: It;'s the [negative binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series#Special_cases)

Comment: I see it now, thank you! I appreciate it.